# How would a manager use a starter and reliever differently in an All-Star game?

Tags: baseball

In a "regular" game, a starter pitches "several" innings while a reliever pitches one or two.

But in the All Star game, "all" pitchers pitch only one to two innings. So what has historically been the difference between the way managers have used starters versus relievers in such a game? For instance, has it been the case that only starters will get to pitch even two innings?

Comment: @jamauss: I changed the question to ask what has been the case historically, That question can be answered factually, and I was wondering if it can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: Good idea - I've voted to re-open. Thanks.